# is it possible with ruby geocoder to get a location 1 mile due south of a given latitude and longitude

Tags: ruby, rails-geocoder

If given a specified latitude and longitude, can I get a location 1 mile due south of it. Say I am given:

```
event lat: 34.0522342                                                                                                                                                                                                  
event lon: -118.2436849
```

and I want a location 1 mile south?

I have seen this: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/5821/calculating-latitude-longitude-x-miles-from-point  but just want to do this in geocoder.

Comment: Why do you want to do us a gem when It can be calculated in a few lines of Ruby code?

Comment: @spickermann : One line should be more than enough :)

Answer (score 1):

The longitude doesn't change when you're moving south.

One degree of latitude has the same length everywhere : `69.1 miles`.

As long as you're not exactly on the North Pole and you're more than 1 mile away from the South Pole, you basically need :

```
lat -= 1/69.1
```

Moving west or east, only the longitude would change but you'd need to take the latitude into account. One degree of longitude is `69.1 miles` on the equator but `0 mile` on the Poles.